# «В пролёте» — это значит остаться не/ни с чем

Tags: орфография, фразеология, не-или-ни

На сайте используют *не*, но мне кажется, надо использовать *ни*. Прав ли я?

> «В пролёте» — это значит остаться **не/ни** с чем, потерпеть фиаско, потерпеть неудачу, остаться обделенным, что то не получить.

[Что значит выражение «В пролёте»?](https://blacklexicon.ru/chto-oznachaet-v-prolyote/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре многих выражений:
**[в пролёте](https://all_words.academic.ru/7356/%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5_%5B%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%2C_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%5D) [быть, остаться]** — в проигрыше, **ни** с чем. *С деньгами мы как всегда в пролёте.*

В толковом словаре практически то же самое:
[пролете́ть — пролета́ть](https://gramota.ru/meta/prolet)
1.3. *разговорное*, неудача, просчёт.
**Фразеология**
В пролёте быть, остаться и т. п. В проигрыше, ***ни** с чем*.

*Он сильно пролетел на какой-то сделке, наделал полно долгов, в общем, **остался ни с чем*** (Н. Вебер. Смертельный бумеранг любви).
[Сильно пролетел = оказался в пролёте.]

*Вторят друг за другом чуть не хором, что одному отказала, другого выставила, в итоге **все в пролёте, ни с чем остались*** (Л. Ксеанелис. Тайное вплетение).

Вы правы — надо использовать ***ни***.
Так что ошибочка вкралась в объяснения по ссылке. И не одна: обратите внимание на ваше любимое "что то не получить". Дефис ведь нужен, правда?

Answer (score 3):

1. **[Из словаря:](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/197285/%D0%9D%D0%B8)**

Современный толковый словарь русского языка **Ефремовой**

**НИ С ЧЕМ:**

**I нареч.** качеств.-обстоят. разг.
**С пустыми руками.**

**II нареч.** качеств.-обстоят. разг.
Не добившись никакого результата, не получив ничего; **безрезультатно**.

2. **Почему пишется НИ?** Рассмотрим, примеру,  сочетание: *не сравнить **ни с чем.*** Здесь частица ***НИ*** усиливает отрицание, выраженное ***НЕ***. Возможно, в дальнейшем оборот стал употребляться самостоятельно как **устойчивое** сочетание, то есть при отсутствии частицы ***НЕ***.
3. Другой вариант **для объяснения.** В русском языке много других устойчивых **оборотов** с частицей НИ, в которых нет отрицания (пропадешь **ни за что**, мне это **ни к чему** и т.д.). В этом случае у НИ двойная функция: **отрицание и усиление.**
4. Но самое **ИНТЕРЕСНОЕ**: форма **НЕ С ЧЕМ** —  ударный вариант, и к это фразе  **вообще не походит.**

Можно сказать: *Остался я **ни с чем**,  да и оставаться-то было **не с чем.** Особого богатства так и не нажил.*